# Not able to render Javascript in selenium to view the rendered page_source

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on extracting info from a Databricks job run history.
But even though the data is loaded in the chrome browser, I am unable to see the data in page_source.
I am using Selenium chrome driver in Python

```
#using this to extract page source
time.sleep(20)
print(driver.page_source)
```

I am pasting the page source I am getting as output here for your reference.

```html
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta name="google" content="notranslate"/><meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en"/><title>Databricks</title><link rel="preload" href="/pub-conf" as="fetch" crossorigin/><link rel="preload" href="/workspaces" as="fetch" crossorigin/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"><script defer="defer" src="/js/main.28c3e037.js"></script></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><script>let logCount = 0;
      function error_handler(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
        if (logCount++ > 4) {
          return;
        }
        const ts = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
        const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          credentials: 'include',
          body: JSON.stringify({uploadTime: ts, items: [
            JSON.stringify({
              eventId: Array.from(window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(Math.ceil(12 / 8)))).map((x) => x.toString(16)).join('').substring(0, 12),
              blob: error && error.stack && error.stack.toString(),
              metric:'jsException',
              tags: {
                eventType: "jsExceptionV3",
                jsExceptionMessage: message,
                jsExceptionSource: source,
                jsExceptionLineno: lineno,
                jsExceptionColno: colno,
                jsExceptionBeforeInit: true,
              },
              ts: ts,
            }),
          ]}),
        };
        fetch('/telemetry?t=' + Date.now(), options);
      };
      window.onerror = error_handler;
      window.onunhandledrejection = function(event) {
        error_handler(String(event.reason));
      };
      window.startupHangTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        error_handler("Startup Hang: Did not init within 60 seconds");
      }, 60000);
      // Prefetch /pubconf, /workspaces, /config
      // We wrap this in a function to not pollute the namespace
      (function() {
        const getParams = (paramsStr) => {
          let match;
          const pl = /\+/g; // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
          const search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g;
          const decode = function decode(s) {
            return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, ' '));
          };

          const urlParams = {};
          match = search.exec(paramsStr);
          while (match) {
            urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
            match = search.exec(paramsStr);
          }
          return urlParams;
        }

        // If we can get it from the params, do that
        const params = getParams(window.location.search.substr(1));
        const workspaceParam = params?.o;

        function fetchWorkspaceConfigUsingParam() {
          let configUsingParamProm = null;
          let configUsingParamOrgId = null;
          if (workspaceParam) {
            configUsingParamOrgId = workspaceParam.toString();
            configUsingParamProm = fetch('/config', {headers: { 'X-Databricks-Org-Id': configUsingParamOrgId }});
          }
          return {
            configUsingParamProm,
            configUsingParamOrgId,
          };
        }

        // Note that this function returns null in cases where there is no workspace or where we want the user to choose a workspace, since we
        // are going to redirect the user anyways
        const maybeGetOrgId = function(workspaceList, pubConf) {
          if (workspaceParam) {
            return workspaceParam;
          }

          // Otherwise we try to infer from the deployment name (apparently this doesn't work for AWS vanity URLs)
          if (pubConf.inferOrgIdFromDeploymentName) {
            const deploymentName = window.location.hostname
                    .split('.')
                    .slice(0, pubConf.numDeploymentNameHostnameLabels)
                    .join('.');
            const targetWorkspace = workspaceList.filter(w => deploymentName === w.deploymentName);
            if (targetWorkspace.length > 0) {
              return targetWorkspace[0].orgId;
            }
          }

          // If we're just going to redirect the user anyways, don't try to fetch the config
          if (pubConf.redirectBrowserOnWorkspaceSelection) {
            return null;
          }

          // Otherwise, if there are either no available workspaces, or multiple confirmed ones, we return null since
          // we will redirect the user anyways
          const confirmedWorkspaces = workspaceList.filter((workspace) => !workspace.needsConfirmation);
          // If there is exactly one confirmed workspace, then we'll pick that one.
          // This is the common path for single tenant
          if (confirmedWorkspaces.length === 1) {
            return confirmedWorkspaces[0].orgId;
          }

          // otherwise we're not sure what workspace they want, so we don't prefetch
          return null;
        };


        const pubConfProm = fetch('/pub-conf').then(r => {
          if (r.status !== 200) {
            throw new Error("Pub-conf Prefetch error: " + r.status);
          }
          return r.json();
        }).then(json => window.pubConf = json);
        const workspacesProm = fetch('/workspaces').then(r => {
          if (r.status !== 200) {
            throw new Error("Workspaces Prefetch error: " + r.status);
          }
          return r.json();
        }).then(json => {
          window.workspaces = json;
        });
        const { configUsingParamProm, configUsingParamOrgId } = fetchWorkspaceConfigUsingParam();

        window.prefetchedSettingsProm = (async () => {
          await Promise.all([pubConfProm, workspacesProm]);

          const orgId = maybeGetOrgId(window.workspaces, window.pubConf);
          let r;
          if (configUsingParamProm && orgId && orgId === configUsingParamOrgId) {
            r = await configUsingParamProm;
          } else if (orgId != null) {
            r = await fetch('/config', {headers: { 'X-Databricks-Org-Id': orgId.toString() }});
          } else {
            throw new Error("could not determine workspace");
          }
          if (r.status !== 200) {
            throw new Error("Prefetch error: " + r.status);
          }
          return await r.json();
        })();
      })();</script><link rel="preload" href="/js/main.28c3e037.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/login/7043.21b43089.chunk.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/login/6499.fedff81a.chunk.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/login/7603.aa36561a.chunk.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/login/5126.a3d96d5a.chunk.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/js/8473.6d11cc58.chunk.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/login/8484.2264fc4c.chunk.js" as="script"><link rel="preload" href="/js/1349.2e50bb47.chunk.js" as="script"><script>function preload(uris) {
        uris.forEach(uri => {
          const preload = document.createElement("link");
          preload.rel = "preload";
          preload.href = uri;
          preload.as = uri.endsWith(".css") ? "style" : "script";
          document.head.appendChild(preload);
        });
      }
      const hash = window.location.hash;
      
      if (hash.indexOf("#notebook/") === 0) {
        preload(["/js/265.3ad79cf4.chunk.js","/js/3961.0340df6c.chunk.js","/js/6874.fdee06a1.chunk.js","/js/1435.b44077be.chunk.js","/js/9897.3e95fdd2.chunk.js","/js/2368.b5d6b718.chunk.js","/js/2241.296f6c2a.chunk.js","/js/1831.b4e9f747.chunk.js","/js/8687.d29f7892.chunk.js","/js/3315.cbbda80a.chunk.js","/js/5463.c0497674.chunk.js","/js/6373.1f043b2c.chunk.js","/js/4817.92a286de.chunk.js","/js/4005.60ef1ef1.chunk.js","/js/7177.f2a13d4d.chunk.js","/js/9982.52705ede.chunk.js","/js/9622.32eaae8f.chunk.js","/js/7682.dcc39dcc.chunk.js","/js/1826.3f8ee844.chunk.js","/js/7414.0d648cb1.chunk.js","/js/6638.2cdb7ba7.chunk.js","/js/6617.d700873b.chunk.js","/js/4287.8519cc0d.chunk.js","/js/740.1ba53506.chunk.js","/js/7973.74903f69.chunk.js","/js/2131.0a22c001.chunk.js","/js/2717.5976e517.chunk.js","/js/736.24f4531e.chunk.js","/js/7814.06c77740.chunk.js","/js/8397.bb51b0f1.chunk.js","/js/9957.e844fe05.chunk.js","/css/6823.ef02c8db.chunk.css","/css/9018.b0960582.chunk.css","/css/3061.632ce97e.chunk.css","/css/8687.8261acdc.chunk.css","/css/7177.8239daa4.chunk.css","/css/ReactNotebookView.68ddf7ec.chunk.css"]);
        preload(["/js/265.3ad79cf4.chunk.js","/js/3961.0340df6c.chunk.js","/js/6874.fdee06a1.chunk.js","/js/1435.b44077be.chunk.js","/js/5449.26bbd0de.chunk.js","/js/8561.36bc28be.chunk.js","/js/296.352a2fd9.chunk.js","/js/615.7b5a7f25.chunk.js","/js/7414.0d648cb1.chunk.js","/js/6638.2cdb7ba7.chunk.js","/js/6617.d700873b.chunk.js","/js/4287.8519cc0d.chunk.js","/js/740.1ba53506.chunk.js","/js/7973.74903f69.chunk.js","/js/2131.0a22c001.chunk.js","/js/3584.5b823085.chunk.js","/js/8827.4a78799d.chunk.js","/js/2205.cbbcc38e.chunk.js","/js/7994.f058ec6c.chunk.js","/css/6823.ef02c8db.chunk.css","/css/9018.b0960582.chunk.css","/css/ScheduleLink.1a0cef1f.chunk.css"]);
      } else if (hash === '') {
        preload(["/js/265.3ad79cf4.chunk.js","/js/6638.2cdb7ba7.chunk.js","/js/400.ee52265e.chunk.js","/js/7032.7572d7be.chunk.js","/css/6823.ef02c8db.chunk.css"]);
        preload(["/js/265.3ad79cf4.chunk.js","/js/5526.775fd734.chunk.js","/js/6638.2cdb7ba7.chunk.js","/js/400.ee52265e.chunk.js","/js/6362.27654e8a.chunk.js"]);
      } else if (hash.indexOf("#job/") === 0) {
        if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof performance === "object" && performance.timeOrigin) {
          preload(['/mfe/jaws/remoteEntry.js?t=' + (performance.timeOrigin)]);
        }
      }
      
      preload([]);</script><div id="skip-links"></div><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="toolbar"><div id="toolbar"></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="tooltip"><div id="tooltip" class="hidden"><p><span id="value"></span></p></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="global-notification-container"><div id="global-notification-container"></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><div id="rmmodal-container"></div><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="topbar"><div id="tb-action-banner-container"></div><div id="topbar" style="display: none"><span id="tb-page-title"></span><h1 class="tb-title-wrapper tb-title-wrapper-central"><span class="tb-title"></span> <span class="tb-title-portal"></span> <span class="tb-title-lang"></span><div class="tb-status"><span class="tb-status-msg tb-status-msg-error"></span> <span class="tb-status-msg tb-status-msg-banner"></span> <span class="tb-status-msg tb-status-msg-locked"></span> <span class="tb-status-msg tb-status-msg-connecting">Connecting...&nbsp;</span> <span class="tb-status-msg tb-status-msg-waiting">Still working...&nbsp;</span> <img class="tb-status-spinner" src="/static/media/spinner.gif" alt="spinner"/></div></h1><div class="tb-title-wrapper tb-title-wrapper-right"><div class="tb-trial-msg"></div><div class="tb-title-icons tb-title-icons-right"></div><div class="tb-status presence"><span class="tb-status-msg tb-status-presence"></span></div><div class="tb-notebook-schedule-link"></div><div class="tb-notebook-share-button"></div></div><div id="tb-invite-teammate"></div><div id="tb-upgrade"></div><a class="tb-button tb-button-right tb-button-upgrade" title="Upgrade" target="_blank"><span>Upgrade</span></a></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><div id="app-root"></div><div id="legacy-app-root"></div><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="filebrowser-popup"><div id="filebrowser-popup" style="display: none"><div class="filebrowser" style="display: none"></div></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="projects-filebrowser-popup"><div id="projects-filebrowser-popup" style="display: none"><div class="filebrowser" style="display: none"></div></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="searchpanel-popup"><div id="searchpanel-popup"><div class="searchpanel" data-panel="Search" style="display: none"></div></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><div id="search-root"></div><div id="onboarding-checklist"></div><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="title-menu"><div id="title-menu" class="tb-title-menu dropdown-menu" role="menu"></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="hidden"><div id="hidden" style="display: none"></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="history"><div id="history" style="display: none"></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="proxy-endpoints-conn-test-iframe"><div id="proxy-endpoints-conn-test-iframe" style="display: none"></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><uses-legacy-bootstrap data-wrapped-element-id="debugHelper"><div id="debugHelper" style="z-index: 1000; display: none; position: fixed; right: 190px; bottom: 0px"><div id="debugRoute" style="position: fixed; right: 190px; bottom: 40px"></div><div id="debugCounters" style="color: var(--primary-text-color); position: fixed; right: 50px; bottom: 20px"></div><a href="/ops/">[OPS]</a> <a href="/ops/debug">Debug</a> <a href="/ops/metrics">Metrics</a> <a href="/ops/requests">Requests</a></div></uses-legacy-bootstrap><script>function addPrefetches(paths) {
        paths.forEach(path => {
          var element = document.createElement('link');
          element.rel = 'prefetch';
          element.href = path;
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element);
        })
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        addPrefetches(["/media/pin-inactive.76cfbd5a.svg","/media/pin-active.3f997394.svg","/media/jupyter_favicon.e5618ffc.svg","/media/azure_devops_logo_hover.afd8ec9e.svg","/media/azure_devops_logo.6f8531ab.svg","/media/glyphicons-halflings.191ce105.png","/media/newslablight-webfont.43dee4a4.eot","/media/newslablight-webfont.1139d78a.woff2","/media/newslablight-webfont.c8d2ffdf.woff","/media/newslablight-webfont.4d6d4f4c.ttf","/media/newslablight-webfont.6db3f979.svg","/media/databricks-regular-webfont.c3085bea.eot","/media/databricks-regular-webfont.de65de42.woff","/media/databricks-regular-webfont.977f0ff5.ttf","/media/databricks-regular-webfont.2f9a86b4.svg","/media/fontawesome-webfont.03605b24.eot","/media/fontawesome-webfont.c589f72d.woff","/media/fontawesome-webfont.45f9f92a.ttf","/media/fontawesome-webfont.d0ba16d8.svg","/media/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.6ee80f4b.woff2","/media/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.bd9b02bf.woff","/media/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.5a588d6a.ttf","/media/KaTeX_AMS-Regular.8d510e21.woff2","/media/KaTeX_AMS-Regular.363668e4.woff","/media/KaTeX_AMS-Regular.79770839.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Bold.0408dbd1.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Bold.dce5f226.woff","/media/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Bold.9958c13a.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Regular.8cb339d8.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Regular.a0f19b9a.woff","/media/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Regular.f35e6d32.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Fraktur-Bold.e9f666bf.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Fraktur-Bold.581882ea.woff","/media/KaTeX_Fraktur-Bold.6fc2b891.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Fraktur-Regular.8fafd264.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Fraktur-Regular.d3067917.woff","/media/KaTeX_Fraktur-Regular.37f0101f.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Main-Bold.e4830ce6.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Main-Bold.77475ba5.woff","/media/KaTeX_Main-Bold.b097bb94.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Main-BoldItalic.baab209e.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Main-BoldItalic.5994f793.woff","/media/KaTeX_Main-BoldItalic.4ab8a635.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Main-Italic.fdfec592.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Main-Italic.a15e0ae8.woff","/media/KaTeX_Main-Italic.ac680e98.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Main-Regular.c904829c.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Main-Regular.9d3ff6bd.woff","/media/KaTeX_Main-Regular.ad5bb259.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Math-Italic.d0dd29d1.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Math-Italic.80956401.woff","/media/KaTeX_Math-Italic.75d88e39.ttf","/media/KaTeX_SansSerif-Bold.1849da20.woff2","/media/KaTeX_SansSerif-Bold.5a8b0e8c.woff","/media/KaTeX_SansSerif-Bold.8a18ba89.ttf","/media/KaTeX_SansSerif-Italic.acb5dce2.woff2","/media/KaTeX_SansSerif-Italic.e7517a35.woff","/media/KaTeX_SansSerif-Italic.3e7cf777.ttf","/media/KaTeX_SansSerif-Regular.167f81e8.woff2","/media/KaTeX_SansSerif-Regular.1bb5e535.woff","/media/KaTeX_SansSerif-Regular.7c572bf7.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Script-Regular.49ff882d.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Script-Regular.7e1d6987.woff","/media/KaTeX_Script-Regular.c73c9054.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Size1-Regular.98c1c5ee.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Size1-Regular.6dff5232.woff","/media/KaTeX_Size1-Regular.41fbe509.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Size2-Regular.9f44db0b.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Size2-Regular.758926c6.woff","/media/KaTeX_Size2-Regular.8f1e2ab9.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Size3-Regular.943a01ec.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Size3-Regular.d27d182e.woff","/media/KaTeX_Size3-Regular.32abfb10.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Size4-Regular.31bd0319.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Size4-Regular.47db69ec.woff","/media/KaTeX_Size4-Regular.9ee4a1fd.ttf","/media/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular.aa9fe3f6.woff2","/media/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular.663eef93.woff","/media/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular.73160645.ttf","/media/fontawesome-webfont.8b43027f.eot","/media/fontawesome-webfont.20fd1704.woff2","/media/fontawesome-webfont.f691f37e.woff","/media/fontawesome-webfont.1e59d233.ttf","/media/fontawesome-webfont.c1e38fd9.svg","/media/spritemap.ac65e273.png","/media/spritemap@2x.7410259a.png","/media/SourceCodePro-Regular.otf.b886e5e4.woff2","/media/SourceCodePro-Bold.otf.0fab52a9.woff2","/media/spinner_green.64cba84f.svg","/media/spinner_red.dfdea22c.svg","/login/login.47926ab1.js","/js/main.28c3e037.js","/js/metrics-graphics.240ef397.js","/login/7251.95fc2945.chunk.css","/login/7251.8c659cfe.chunk.js","/media/BMT_logo_large.06a08317.svg","/media/databricks_community_edition.2359b37e.png","/login/6499.fedff81a.chunk.js","/login/7603.aa36561a.chunk.js","/css/1349.6b186478.chunk.css","/js/1349.2e50bb47.chunk.js","/media/partner-connect-icon.8a202243.svg","/media/alert.49c5db30.svg","/media/blocked.a81a311f.svg","/media/book.31f15827.svg","/media/branch.3a7e8c0d.svg","/media/cancelled.2ad6d232.svg","/media/circle_error.e3c3b9a4.svg","/media/cloud.8b8c5eb0.svg","/media/cluster.4a93f2e9.svg","/media/dashboard.8758e581.svg","/media/data-quality.1e5b9672.svg","/media/expand-icon-flipped.77c0871a.svg","/media/fa-columns.76f151f6.svg","/media/fa-table.015b0dc7.svg","/media/failed.789ca99e.svg","/media/filled-gray-circle.7d2d5039.svg","/media/filled-green-circle.ed636499.svg","/media/folder.78745b36.svg","/media/paused.536d6b5d.svg","/media/pending.b8ba238e.svg","/media/query.35fed909.svg","/media/running.ec723323.svg","/media/skipped.b25c88c7.svg","/media/spinner_blue.8d29a816.svg","/media/success.a741e81b.svg","/media/table.7b8cc615.svg","/media/terminated.63ea598d.svg","/media/timed_out.3857e04c.svg","/media/waiting.6f50f9b4.svg","/media/warning.6198e47b.svg","/login/9882.7556e9e0.chunk.js","/login/7043.21b43089.chunk.js","/login/8062.11dbe846.chunk.js","/login/2957.9f99525d.chunk.js","/login/5649.7878ab16.chunk.js","/login/8538.9a6cf4ae.chunk.js","/login/969.6bf80188.chunk.js","/login/862.51b04181.chunk.js","/login/5396.b306568e.chunk.js","/login/9565.9ad08ba9.chunk.js","/login/462.952815d1.chunk.js","/js/9820.5bab95cf.chunk.js","/css/639.768a06d7.chunk.css","/js/639.d8276d0a.chunk.js","/css/8730.f2124aac.chunk.css","/js/8730.7b113aba.chunk.js","/js/6537.6e212bcd.chunk.js","/media/stitch.34c97b52.svg","/media/fivetran.5bb015fe.png","/media/infoworks.7df5f41f.png","/media/qlik.4c6468fd.png","/media/streamsets.3710f31a.png","/media/syncsort.44d5ff89.jpg","/css/GraphqlClustersGetPage.20009756.chunk.css","/js/6471.6b9e370f.chunk.js","/css/NewClustersEditPage.09fbd5ef.chunk.css","/js/4602.7ab61ee7.chunk.js","/css/ClustersMainPage.1c9a080c.chunk.css","/js/2851.a766ba08.chunk.js","/css/SimpleClusterCreatePage.09fbd5ef.chunk.css","/js/7028.313d9947.chunk.js","/css/ClustersCreatePage.09fbd5ef.chunk.css","/js/9463.da593c56.chunk.js","/css/PoolRoutesPages.8e6dfbe2.chunk.css","/js/7274.b3176703.chunk.js","/css/ClusterPoliciesRouteUtils.f3101d86.chunk.css","/js/8540.8d62df5e.chunk.js","/js/3235.b0c75e7f.chunk.js","/css/AdminConsoleView.3cd1bba7.chunk.css","/js/5198.cfc4bbcc.chunk.js","/css/UserSettingsView.92c8234c.chunk.css","/js/9152.ecb54c6d.chunk.js","/media/if_lightbulb.5e2e71fa.svg","/js/6362.27654e8a.chunk.js","/media/import_illustration.4151f89c.svg","/media/notebook_illustration.d0d5ad3b.svg","/media/partner_connect_illustration.8a202243.svg","/media/quickstart_illustration.3c391acf.svg","/media/references_illustration.e67339f9.svg","/js/7032.7572d7be.chunk.js","/media/General_icon.78cbb670.svg","/media/Python_icon.b89e5ec9.svg","/media/R_icon.c159ddc0.svg","/media/Scala_icon.d90ef464.svg","/media/add_data_icon.3b26b6be.svg","/media/code_icon.16b52873.svg","/media/help_doc_icon.679cb6f8.svg","/media/icon-import-data.2fb512d3.svg","/media/icon-new-notebook.2bc783e0.svg","/media/icon-quickstart-notebook.62cf29ed.svg","/media/icon-upload-data-non-drop-zone.e76fe775.svg","/media/icon-upload-data.3e579a80.svg","/media/persona_nav.35794a3b.gif","/css/LibraryView.2e69635a.chunk.css","/js/2662.beedbf76.chunk.js","/js/1511.12475684.chunk.js","/css/ClustersGetMetricsPage.09fbd5ef.chunk.css","/js/5355.bcf82c4c.chunk.js","/js/5148.d308de7a.chunk.js","/css/PipelinesMainPage.46640809.chunk.css","/js/1710.eab7735c.chunk.js","/js/7676.a3d7a7ae.chunk.js","/media/collapsingAllIcon.734ff2cb.svg","/media/expandingAllIcon.53164af4.svg","/js/3214.ae272d39.chunk.js","/js/2667.346c259c.chunk.js","/media/ml_dashboard_ill_automl.e024a05f.svg","/media/ml_dashboard_ill_feature_store.37dd40c0.svg","/media/ml_dashboard_ill_notebook.2993bcc7.svg","/media/ml_dashboard_ill_reference_solutions.8093cd75.svg","/media/ml_dashboard_ill_training.095fbd61.svg","/css/ExperimentObservatoryPage.eae8a832.chunk.css","/js/3637.5912802f.chunk.js","/css/AutoMLConfigurationPage.3af21a7b.chunk.css","/js/2689.7b6b2141.chunk.js","/js/9981.ab3e6f39.chunk.js","/js/5197.fc4b3e76.chunk.js","/js/8732.cb41214f.chunk.js","/js/3449.d55be0e4.chunk.js","/js/199.4c6eb3b4.chunk.js","/js/4286.b1e59071.chunk.js","/js/2384.691a4cb0.chunk.js","/js/3345.5e60f27e.chunk.js","/css/CreateWorkspaceLibraryPage.a7702194.chunk.css","/js/8553.b7373a0f.chunk.js","/css/CreateMlflowExperimentPage.ee2d4c7e.chunk.css","/js/6595.ae5d909c.chunk.js","/css/ScheduleLink.1a0cef1f.chunk.css","/js/7994.f058ec6c.chunk.js","/js/419.a53bb5a3.chunk.js","/css/ReactNotebookView.68ddf7ec.chunk.css","/js/9957.e844fe05.chunk.js","/media/placeholder_pic.157f088b.png","/media/tabbed_results_announce.2c4b9566.gif","/css/DashboardEditView.ea078db7.chunk.css","/js/2882.03efce2b.chunk.js","/css/DashboardPresentView.fceb6112.chunk.css","/js/8985.c89f21e8.chunk.js","/css/TableGetPage.e5f37737.chunk.css","/js/4227.63f45c4a.chunk.js","/js/2184.8a58eb28.chunk.js","/js/8155.c9616b56.chunk.js","/js/5402.61f8dd3d.chunk.js","/js/5244.61ebb5cb.chunk.js","/css/2009.09fbd5ef.chunk.css","/js/2009.05795c52.chunk.js","/media/mlflow_cluster_libraries_icon.adffc652.svg","/media/mlflow_cluster_spec_icon.001d116c.svg","/media/mlflow_notebook_revision_icon.8f838dbc.svg","/js/3080.c9c93b1f.chunk.js","/js/5290.536d9da4.chunk.js","/media/logged_model.dd9b21ff.svg","/media/registered_model.f2b0e698.svg","/media/view_notebook_revision.06996110.svg","/js/4136.0c92b01d.chunk.js","/js/5122.77668f56.chunk.js","/media/countries.geo.da867aec.json","/media/japan.prefectures.geo.503032a2.json","/media/usa-albers.geo.4d6ceca8.json","/js/2713.f27cb942.chunk.js","/js/7561.8de45682.chunk.js","/js/265.3ad79cf4.chunk.js","/js/3961.0340df6c.chunk.js","/js/6874.fdee06a1.chunk.js","/css/6823.ef02c8db.chunk.css","/js/1435.b44077be.chunk.js","/js/9897.3e95fdd2.chunk.js","/css/9018.b0960582.chunk.css","/css/3061.632ce97e.chunk.css","/js/2368.b5d6b718.chunk.js","/js/2241.296f6c2a.chunk.js","/js/1831.b4e9f747.chunk.js","/css/8687.8261acdc.chunk.css","/js/8687.d29f7892.chunk.js","/js/5449.26bbd0de.chunk.js","/js/3315.cbbda80a.chunk.js","/js/5463.c0497674.chunk.js","/js/6373.1f043b2c.chunk.js","/js/4817.92a286de.chunk.js","/js/9487.6d0c3e50.chunk.js","/js/4005.60ef1ef1.chunk.js","/css/7177.8239daa4.chunk.css","/js/7177.f2a13d4d.chunk.js","/js/9982.52705ede.chunk.js","/js/8561.36bc28be.chunk.js","/js/9622.32eaae8f.chunk.js","/js/7682.dcc39dcc.chunk.js","/js/1202.1651745c.chunk.js","/js/296.352a2fd9.chunk.js","/js/615.7b5a7f25.chunk.js","/login/5126.1b33304e.chunk.css","/login/5126.a3d96d5a.chunk.js","/js/5526.775fd734.chunk.js","/js/3112.229db2c0.chunk.js","/css/9097.b7c5aca9.chunk.css","/js/789.7055c3e7.chunk.js","/js/6122.a583f800.chunk.js","/js/3953.bc4a0338.chunk.js","/js/5850.b9610775.chunk.js","/css/8473.a91be41f.chunk.css","/js/8473.6d11cc58.chunk.js","/css/9822.c697d92c.chunk.css","/js/9822.a6f219f0.chunk.js","/js/1826.3f8ee844.chunk.js","/login/7628.be1062f4.chunk.js","/js/2180.77c8b226.chunk.js","/js/3949.0ba9a432.chunk.js","/js/177.7d26e136.chunk.js","/js/2122.aeb0bf45.chunk.js","/js/7414.0d648cb1.chunk.js","/js/6638.2cdb7ba7.chunk.js","/js/6617.d700873b.chunk.js","/js/4287.8519cc0d.chunk.js","/js/740.1ba53506.chunk.js","/js/7973.74903f69.chunk.js","/js/2131.0a22c001.chunk.js","/js/5489.e0232314.chunk.js","/js/2717.5976e517.chunk.js","/media/us-map.6cab3846.json","/media/world-map.282fccf1.json","/media/ellipse-2s-30px.df5b6e08.gif","/js/3584.5b823085.chunk.js","/js/520.57827eea.chunk.js","/js/6267.26b62d2c.chunk.js","/js/1342.f3c1945c.chunk.js","/js/736.24f4531e.chunk.js","/js/400.ee52265e.chunk.js","/js/8827.4a78799d.chunk.js","/login/8484.2264fc4c.chunk.js","/media/spinner.7aa77051.svg","/media/bmt-favicon.dfa4ca84.ico","/js/7814.06c77740.chunk.js","/js/9418.cfc92d91.chunk.js","/js/2630.4613696c.chunk.js","/js/367.378e8204.chunk.js","/js/1913.37480a3a.chunk.js","/js/3846.23b54ba1.chunk.js","/js/2205.cbbcc38e.chunk.js","/js/8397.bb51b0f1.chunk.js","/js/4332.4717d0c6.chunk.js","/js/2960.d7334d50.chunk.js","/js/5397.089d60be.chunk.js","/js/9628.69417888.chunk.js","/js/9167.c719483d.chunk.js","/js/4188.000cbe6c.chunk.js","/js/438.be5d16dd.chunk.js","/static/media/spinner.gif","/login/DB_Azure_Lockup_2x.png","/login/bootstrap.min.css","/login/databricks_ce_icon.svg","/login/databricks_logoTM_rgb_TM.svg","/login/favicon.ico","/login/logo_2020/azure_databricks.png","/login/logo_2020/databricks.svg","/login/logo_2020/databricks_community_edition.png","/delta_sharing/databricks.svg","/delta_sharing/download.svg","/delta_sharing/retrieve_config.html","/delta_sharing/sharing.css","/delta_sharing/sharing.js","/delta_sharing/logo/apachespark.png","/delta_sharing/logo/atscale.png","/delta_sharing/logo/azuresynapse.png","/delta_sharing/logo/bigquery.png","/delta_sharing/logo/databricks.png","/delta_sharing/logo/dremio.png","/delta_sharing/logo/looker.png","/delta_sharing/logo/pandas.png","/delta_sharing/logo/powerbi.png","/delta_sharing/logo/presto.png","/delta_sharing/logo/python.png","/delta_sharing/logo/qlik.png","/delta_sharing/logo/starburst.png","/delta_sharing/logo/tableau.png","/delta_sharing/logo/trino.png","/static/iframe.html","/static/css/sparkui-iframe.css","/static/js/heap/heap-1473692602.js","/static/js/heap/heap-210092139.js","/static/js/heap/heap-3428506230.js","/favicon.ico","/login.html",])
      }, 30000)</script><div id="emotion-container-webapp-css"></div></body></html>
```

Can someone help me extract the data after all this javascript is rendered?

Comment: Possibly you get `<title>Databricks</title>` only after logging in. Else without logging I find `<title>Try Databricks - Unified Data Analytics Platform for Data Engineering</title>` Do you have demo creds for us to test?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium No unfortunately I do not have any extra demo creds. Is there another way?